# Logger for a nodejs server application

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, logging

I'm looking for a way to store console.log messages, and be able to access them fast and search through them by keyword fast.

currently im using a simple text file, but when the file becomes large there is some lag because i have to load the whole file in memory.

Comment: Note too that you can use `grep` which doesn't need to load a whole file into memory to search.

Comment: if you are using using aws.. then you can use cloudwatch

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Elastic Stack](https://www.elastic.co/products).

Basically, you dump your log data into an database ([Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch)) and query it with a tool ([Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana)) that can display nice reports for you.

You can still keep a local rotating log file, in the event you lose your connectivity to Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston). You can make custom transports (file, memory, console, network, etc) or put limits on file sizes and many other details.

Comment: Winston is excellent!  However, the key here is searching through the data.  See my answer for a solution for that.  I personally use Winston, with a transport that dumps right into Elasticsearch.

Comment: Then maybe best solution is to create custom transport to write directly to Elasticserach, instead of creating log file and dump it to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting.  :-)  Most people like to write to a file too, in case they lose their Elasticsearch connection.  It depends on your needs.